# Login loop in Kali linux 2021.4

Tags: login, kali-linux, vnc

I am  using kali linux 2021.4 xfce . I have done some .vnc file configuration and rebooted the system .
But now i am not able to log in ,But I can access the GUI through a VNC session. When i try to type username and password it just ask to again without any error. I have done `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` but not fixed the issue. I have upgraded to 2021.4 a week ago and the problem was not there . Pls help if anyone know the answer your help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen something like that in one of my own Kali machines.

Get to a Log in screen and use Ctrl-Alt-F1 to get to a terminal screen.

Run:

sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get autoclean && sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get autoremove

Then restart and see if the machine now runs normally.

Kali is not very forgiving for some kinds of changes / errors. I have had to recover Kali machines from backups.

At this point, back up all your data and run the Kali installer again.

**Follow up:**  For experimental work in Kali, I keep Kali as a virtual machine and these are easy to back up and recover from without reinstalling.

Comment: No, I have tried that but no use

Comment: You may need to reinstall Kali and I amended my answer accordingly.

Comment: But I can access the system /GUI through a VNC session so there is no damage to system i guess

Comment: True, but I have made changes that I was not able to undo. That was my point about changes (that I did not think caused damage).

Comment: Hmm so ,another reinstall : ( .Thank you for your help

Comment: If you are willing, you might consider marking my answer as helpful.